# How to automatically optimize images after loading?

Tags: image, google-app-engine, image-optimization

Let's say i have a form with input `type="file"`. Is there any way to automatically optimize image when onchange event was triggered?
I'm not sure if this is possible, but i know that in WordPress ecosystem there are a lot of plugins for auto optimize each image on load. 
I'm also wondering where it's better to perform optimization: on client side or server side? 
P.S. app is hosted on google cloud platform if it's important

Comment: GCP is a very big ecosystem, you should be a lot more specific... https://cloud.google.com/products/

Comment: We use COMPUTE ENGINE

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ImageKit.io](https://imagekit.io). Directly upload from client or server side and always get optimized images. You can also use URL based transformation parameters.